# How to display only Time value in User Contact without the Current Date value

Tags: custom-fields, webform-civicrm

I have created a custom field selecting date type,selecting the date format and time.Actually I will need only Time field but the system doesn't alow to create
custom field of type date, without selecting a date format and later in webforms I selected Time widget. In webform it is displayed as time field only
But after  the user submits the webform, In civicrm contact current date is also displayed with the time(screenshot)and How to get only the Time value in civicrm?I need this field for time of birth of the user.
[image]
Any help?

Comment: why don't you create a text field and save the value from webform to custom field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using date field it won't allow you to store only time. One option would be to use custom field of type text to only store time or use date field to store DOB with time.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: What is DOB and What is HTH?

Comment: DOB - Date of Birth, HTH - Hope That Helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom field (type = textfield) to store only time.